# Double quotes on a regex patter string causing failure of regular expression search

Tags: python, regex

**rx**

[Here's the sample table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mNgTP.png)

**code**

```
pii_list = rx['pii'].tolist()
rxpattern_list = rx['rxpattern'].tolist()

print(rxpattern_list) 
["rf'^(?:age)*(?:age)(?:age)*$'", "rf'^(?:birth)*(?:birth|place|country|txt)(?:birth)*$'", "rf'^(?:car)*(?:car|license|number|nb)(?:car)*$'", "rf'^(?:citizen)*(?:citizen|country|ship|code|cd|txt)(?:citizen)*$'", "rf'^(?:birth)*(?:birth|date|dt|dob)(?:birth)*$'", "rf'^(?:gender)*(?:gender)(?:gender)*$'", "rf'^(?:home)*(?:address|home|city|street|country|line|txt|postal|zip|flat|floor|door|[0-9])(?:home)*$'", "rf'^(?:home)*(?:home|phone|nbr|number)(?:home)*$'"] 

print(pii_list)
['Age', 'Birthplace/country', 'Car license plate number', 'Citizenship country', 'Date of birth', 'Gender', 'Home address', 'Home phone']
pi = pii_list[0]
regx = rxpattern_list[0]
```

pi >>>   'Age'

regx >>> "rf'^(?:age)*(?:age)(?:age)*$'"

```
def pattern_match(pi,regx):
    df["field_friendly_name"] = np.where(df["field_name"].str.contains(regx, case=False, na=False),pi,"")
    df["is_included_in_report"] = np.where(df["field_name"].str.contains(regx, case=False, na=False),True,"")
    temp_df = df[df.field_friendly_name.str.match(pi,flags=re.IGNORECASE)]
    return temp_df

pattern_match(pi,regx)
```

No error but failing to provide any output.

If I explicitly change the regex pattern without quotes, it gives proper output.

`"rf'^(?:age)*(?:age)(?:age)*$'"` to just `rf'^(?:age)*(?:age)(?:age)*$'` with out quotes in place of regx in code, it works.

```
def pattern_match(pi,regx):
    df["field_friendly_name"] = np.where(df["field_name"].str.contains(rf'^(?:age)*(?:age)(?:age)*$', case=False, na=False),pi,"")
    df["is_included_in_report"] = np.where(df["field_name"].str.contains(rf'^(?:age)*(?:age)(?:age)*$', case=False, na=False),True,"")
    temp_df = df[df.field_friendly_name.str.match(pi,flags=re.IGNORECASE)]
    return temp_df

pattern_match(pi,regx)
```

Comment: So, what is your question? `rf'^(?:age)*(?:age)(?:age)*$'` works and is correct.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52360537/i-know-of-f-strings-but-what-are-r-strings-are-there-others The `rf` denotes the type of string. It shouldn't be in the quotes.

Comment: if i use variable 'regx' in code it doesn't work

Comment: I guess your variable `regx` is `"rf'^(?:age)*(?:age)(?:age)*$'"` instead of `rf'^(?:age)*(?:age)(?:age)*$'`.

Comment: @user1558604 yes, I know but I'm getting regex from a list which having pattern without double quotes but if assign to a value and display the variable it is coming with quotes

Comment: Then your problem is not the regex, but how you get those strings. You need to give us more details on that.

Comment: @Feodoran yes how can we fix this ?

Comment: What do you get if you `print(rxpattern_list)`

Comment: See how to create a [mcve]. How can we debug your problem if we don't have your problem?

Comment: And where is `rxpattern_list` coming from?

Comment: Edit the question and make it better. Don't put it in the comments.

Comment: I'm editing my question

Comment: The problem is your data source, it should pass the regex as string, not as a string representing a string. A quick-and-dirty solution would be to pass these strings through `eval()`, but I **strongly advice against that** for security reasons.

Comment: what is the solution for this ?

Comment: Do you have access to whatever generates this table? Where is `rx` coming from?

Comment: yes I do, please see my answer below for more information of how it generates the table rx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although it is possible to fix the `"rf'abc'"` strings using `eval()`, this option has some serious security issues and should not be used.

A better solution is to fix these string at their source. The function `pattern_gen()` is returning these wrapped strings, and can be modified to return the strings directly:

```
def pattern_gen(x, y, z):
    return rf'^(?:{y})*(?:{z})(?:{y})*$'

rx.rxpattern = pd.DataFrame(rx.apply(lambda x: pattern_gen(x['kw'], x['mand_kw'], x['kw']), axis=1))
```

Answer (score -1):

Here's the source for rx table

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import re

df = pd.read_csv("Default-Profile.csv")
# read csv files 

df = pd.read_csv("Default-Profile.csv")
rx = pd.read_csv("pii_kws.csv")
# define an empty csv file with column names



# create a new column rxpattern and add to rx dataframe
rx['rxpattern'] = ''

# define a function load regex pattern in column rxpattern in rx

def pattern_gen(x, y, z):
    pattern = rf'^(?:{y})*(?:{z})(?:{y})*$'
    quote = "'"
    return "rf'" + pattern + quote
rx.rxpattern = pd.DataFrame(rx.apply(lambda x: pattern_gen(x['kw'], x['mand_kw'], x['kw']), axis=1))
```

Comment: in `pattern_gen()`, use `return pattern`

Comment: And why do you put this as an answer, instead of an edit of the question?

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't understand where to use `return pattern`

Comment: so that it would be easier for others to make out otherwise it would be very lengthy code

Comment: `def pattern_gen(x, y, z):  return rf'^(?:{y})*(?:{z})(?:{y})*$'`

Comment: You could delete all the actual regex stuff from your questions (`pattern_match`), because that is not the problem.

Comment: Yes, `def pattern_gen(x, y, z):  return rf'^(?:{y})*(?:{z})(?:{y})*$'` has helped to fix this issue. thanks Can you create a answer I will flag that you answered it and I will delete my answer